# Dynamically initialize class using namespace in php

Tags: php, namespaces

I new to name space in php, i am trying to initiate class dynamically using name space but it says class not found.

my folder structure as 
-helper/automationhelper.php
-pageobject/test.php

Automationhelper.php

```
namespace helper;
use helper\ExcelHelper;


class UIAutomationHelper {

// UI Automation Initiator.
public function initiator() {
    $excelhelper = new ExcelHelper();
    $testdata = $excelhelper->readTestData (); //here reading test.xls so the screen name[0] = test;
    $screen_name = array_keys ( $testdata );
    if (isset ( $screen_name [0] )) {  
        $pageObjectname = CommonHelper::replace_string ( '_', "", $screen_name [0] );
        $pageInstance = new $pageObjectname; //here throws exception class not found.
        $dependency_flag = false;
                            // $excelhelper->writeTestCaseResponse($response, $workbook, $sheetname, $rows);
                        } else {
                            // error_log(var_export("method not found->".$method));
                        }
    }
}
```

test.php:-

```
 use helper\PortalHelper as PortalHelper;

 class test {
   private $portalHelperObj;
    public function __construct() {
         $this->portalHelperObj = PortalHelper::getClassInstance ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `CommonHelper` class in the `helper` namespace as well?

Comment: What namespace is your `test` class under? Unless it is `helper` then this wont work. You either have to add `use namespaceWhereTestIs` to your AutomationHelper or include full namespace `new pageobject\test` (assuming namespace of `test` is the same as name of containing folder in provided structure)

Comment: sry i missed add the name space in this, test is with name space pageobject. and i tried to create 'pageobjec\'.$pageObjectname(), but it says class not found.